# Change the copy of the list without changing the orginal one in Lisp

Tags: list, lisp

How can I change the elements of a list's copy without changing the elements of the original list in Common Lisp?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  A very direct answer would be "copy the list, and modify the copy rather than the original." That's unlikely what you want though, so we need more detail.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: it's not that unlikely, since structure sharing in lists is quite common in Lisp. It might not easily be clear what a copy is and what not.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I agree.  That's why OP needs to provide more information (e.g., what kind of modifications are proposed, what kind of copy is needed, etc.).  The "direct" answer works insofar as "copy" means whatever it needs to mean in order for "modify" to work.

Comment: My program is maze solver . The program read the maze from text file as a list and read numbers of strat points. My problem is when the program deal with the first start point , it change the list of maze fir example marke the path by using + character . Then when the second start point is considering , the list of maze changed depending on the first start point. I want the list of maze dose not change with every start point. I tried copy list but it does not work . Please if you have any idea that will be appreciated .

Comment: @Arwa Alsubhi: you can edit your question to make it useful.

Comment: @ArwaAlsubhi It sounds like perhaps your maze is actually a list of lists, and you're modifying sublists. That's not the same as modifying the main list.  You might want to look into functional data structures so that you can get a new maze state without copying the entire maze structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the list with `COPY-LIST`. The you can delete or add elements of the new list and the old list won't change.

Answer (score 3):

`copy-list` copies the top level structure of its argument list. If you intend to surgically modify the values inside, you will need to copy them as well.

```
[3]> (defvar a (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4) 5 (list 6)))
((1 2) (3 4) 5 (6))
[4]> (defvar b (copy-list a))
B
[5]> b
((1 2) (3 4) 5 (6))
[6]> (setf (third b) 55)
55
[7]> b
((1 2) (3 4) 55 (6))
[8]> a
((1 2) (3 4) 5 (6))     ;; top level value changed independently 
[9]> (setf (second (second b)) 44)
44
[10]> b
((1 2) (3 44) 55 (6))
[11]> a
((1 2) (3 44) 5 (6))    ;; deeper change reflected in the original
```

So before you make a deeper change, do make a deeper copy, as `(setf (second b) (copy-list (second a)))`, first:

```
[12]> (setf (second b) (copy-list (second a)))
(3 44)
[13]> (setf (second (second b)) 444)
444
[14]> b
((1 2) (3 444) 55 (6))
[15]> a
((1 2) (3 44) 5 (6))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make new `cons` until the element you want to replace. Eg.

```
; example
(defparameter *test* '(1 2 (3 4 5 6) 7 8))

;; change 4 in the structure in *test* to 99
(list* (car *test*) 
       (cadr *test*)
       (list* (caaddr *test*)
              99               ; the actual change
              (cdaddr *test*)) ; shared sublist tail
       (cdddr *test*))         ; shared tail
; ==> (1 2 (3 99 4 5 6) 7 8)
```

Here the end of the sublist and the end of the main list shares structure since it doesn't need to be changed.

How to search a tree and replace one subtree with another:

```
;; replace all occurences of target in source with replacement
(defun find-replace (source target replacement) 
  (cond ((equal source target) replacement)                ;; equal, return replacement
        ((not (consp source)) source)                      ;; not equal && not pair, return source
        (t (cons (find-replace (car source) target replacement) ;; recurse
                 (find-replace (cdr source) target replacement)))))

(find-replace *test* 4 99)               ; ==> (1 2 (3 99 4 5 6) 7 8)
(find-replace *test* '(3 4 5 6) "banan") ; ==> (1 2 "banan" 7 8)
```